# Does stealing via "Mug" also count towards the Talent for Acquisition trophy?

Tags: achievements, ps4, final-fantasy-10

I'm playing the FFX Remaster for PS4 and was looking through the trophies when I came across this one:

> A Talent for Acquisition - Steal successfully with Rikku 200 times.

Can this be unlocked via the ability, Mug (Steal ability + damage), or does it have to be the actual Steal ability?

After a quick Google on the matter, I found a [forum thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/359870/discussions/0/364042262879120931/) about an (unrelated) issue with this trophy. The last post in the thread claimed you could use either but had no evidence backing this claim, so I don't really want to take this as gospel.

The FF wiki page only lists the trophy name, picture and description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The page for this trophy on PlayStationTrophies.org](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/final-fantasy-x-hd/trophy/77622--A-Talent-for-Acquisition-.html) says that you are able to use Mug to earn this trophy as well as Steal.

> This trophy is very direct in its wording; with Rikku successfully steal items 200 times. Rikku starts with the "Steal" ability and you can steal from every enemy in the game. This trophy can also be earned by using the "Mug" ability. So keep stealing and this trophy will pop on the 200th successful steal.

This is backed up in the comments on that page as well as other threads, like [this one](https://www.truetrophies.com/t73964/a-talent-for-acquisition-trophy):

> I can confirm that 'Mug' also counts towards the trophy as it unlocked when I used mug

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the answer I was looking/hoping for, makes life a bit easier!

Comment: @Supergoat21 glad it worked out in your favor :)